# click button to populate Outlook email from fields in MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access, outlook

I'm trying to improve my knowledge of MS Access to benefit my companies operations. at the moment I'm trying to use information from a Form to populate an email. I've kept it basic to ensure I have the theory correct before adding further information.

I have a table called `ClientListtbl` and a Form called `ClientListfrm`.
I want a button to generate an email prepopulated with the Email Address (field named is `EmailAddress`) in the "TO" part of the email and the Last Name (field named `LastName`) in the subject. I will want to put a "Notes" field into the email body eventually but thought better to start small.
after trawling stackoverflow and other resources I came across a code that seemed to fit and retrofitted it to my database, the code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()

    Dim LastName As Variant
    Dim Email As Variant
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object

    LastName = ClientListfrm!LastName
    Email = ClientListfrm!EmailAddress

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objEmail
     .To = Email
     .Subject = LastName
     .send
End With

    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

`EmailAddress` is short text
`LastName` is Short text

when I then click the button I get an error stating

> run-time error '424' Object required

clicking on debug `LastName = ClientListfrm!LastName` is highlighted. So i tried changing LastName and EmailAddress to As Object. which gives the same error.

any help much appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply a syntax error in the way you are trying to call the field in the form. This worked for me, but there may be other methods:

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()

Dim LastName As Variant
    Dim Email As Variant
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object

    LastName = Forms("ClientListfrm").LastName
    Email = Forms("ClientListfrm").EmailAddress

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objEmail
     .To = Email
     .Subject = LastName
     .send
End With

    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This - with a reference to Outlook - works for me:

```vb
Private Sub Command20_Click()

    Dim LastName As Variant
    Dim Email As Variant
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    LastName = "Macron"           'ClientListfrm!LastName
    Email = "someone@example.com" 'ClientListfrm!EmailAddress

    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .To = Email
        .Subject = LastName
        .send
    End With
    
    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

So, what's missing is probably the syntax for the form controls:

```vb
    LastName = Forms!ClientListfrm!LastName.Value
    Email = Forms!ClientListfrm!EmailAddress.Value
```

Comment: both you and DMclaren below have provided the same answer which has sorted the problem. sadly I can't tick both and the upward arrow for helpful won't show as I'm still new.  but I wanted to convey my thanks to you too.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hi Gustav, hope you had a great weekend. I have a few additions I'd like some help with, I wondered if it's better to make a whole new question or add them to this? it's simply to have the email not send automatically, the user would need to review and click send. and then to add some information from the form into the email body itself.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm no Outlook expert, so a new question is preferable.